# Sorting não funciona

Tags: c++, algoritmo, classificação

Tive que implementar meu próprio sort, usando o selection sort. Porém, o simples código (analisei várias vezes, e pra mim está correto) dá resultados estranhos.

```
template <typename T> void swap(T& var, T& var1)
{
    T temp = var;
    var = var1;
    var1 = temp;
}
template <typename T> void selection_sort(T* begin, T* end, unsigned pos = 0) //1 3 5 2 4; tamanho 5
{
    if(begin != end)
    {
        for(int i = pos+1; i < (end - begin) + pos; i++)
        {
            if(begin[pos] > begin[i]) swap(begin[pos], begin[i]);
        }
        selection_sort(begin+1, end, pos+1);
    }
    else return;
}
//resultado 1 3 0 5 0
```

O que há de errado? O que deve ser feito para arrumá-lo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há uma série de fatores envolvidos aqui.

Primeiramente, o erro está em passar `begin+1` e `pos+1` para a chamada recursiva do `selection_sort`. Ao se acrescentar 1 ao `begin`, você efetivamente perde elementos, uma vez que ao somar 1 à `pos`, por exemplo, na segunda iteração, você estará pegando o índice 1 de um vetor que já foi incrementado, assim, você está pegando o elemento 2.

Corrigindo seu código ficaria assim (já adaptando a nova condição de parada):

```
template <typename T> void selection_sort(T* begin, T* end, unsigned pos = 0)
{
    if(pos < ((end - begin) - 1))
    {
        for(int i = pos+1; i < (end - begin); i++)
        {
            if(begin[pos] > begin[i]) swap(begin[pos], begin[i]);
        }
        selection_sort(begin, end, pos+1);
    }
    else return;
}
```

Contudo, apesar de funcionar, há mais algumas coisas que poderiam ser arrumadas aqui:

- o `else return;` é inútil
- o selection sort poderia ser feito sem recursão, aliás, gastaria menos memória fazendo com dois `for`, em vez de com recursão
- utilizar o resultado da subtração dos vetores para obter um número inteiro (no seu caso, o tamanho do vetor) não é muito aconselhável... eu substituiria o parâmetro `T* end` por `int count`, já que `end` não é utilizado para nada, mesmo
- o parâmetro `unsigned pos` deveria ser substituído por `int pos`, para fazer com que o tipo coincida (você está utilizando `int` para `i`, mas `unsigned` para `pos`)

Para exemplificar como ficaria com essas alterações que eu sugeri:

```
template <typename T> void selection_sort(T* begin, int count)
{
    for (int pos = 0; pos < count - 1; pos++)
    {
        for (int i = pos+1; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (begin[pos] > begin[i]) swap(begin[pos], begin[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta e pelo comentário em relação às melhorias; porém você apontou um erro que não existe: Ao se acrescentar 1 ao begin, você efetivamente perde elementos. Este, simplesmente, é o objetivo. Ele não altera a memória de begin ao usar o *, mas sim altera o parâmetro em relação. Eu alteraria a memória de begin se antes da chamada recursiva eu adicionasse "begin++"

Comment: O erro não está em avançar o ponteiro `begin` para a próxima iteração da recursão (através de `begin+1`). O erro está em fazer *ao mesmo tempo* `begin+1` e `pos+1`. Ao fazer `begin+1` você iniciará a próxima iteração no próximo elemento (na próxima iteração `begin[0]` já traria o próximo elemento). Mas como você também faz `pos+1`, você acaba pulando um elemento a mais na próxima iteração. Repare como a minha primeira solução tira o `begin+1` mas deixa o `pos+1`, ao passo que a solução sugerida pelo @lucas-nunes deixa o `begin+1` mas tira o `pos+1`. Ou seja, nenhuma tem os dois ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado.

Comment: Com o else return eu me sinto melhor sabendo que o código vai parar, mesmo sendo óbvio hahahaha

Comment: Eu não vou trocar end por int count por um motivo: implementei-o para usar com iterators.

Comment: Ah, entendi a ideia do iterator. Ok!

Answer (score 1):

O erro está na inicialização do `i`, onde está `pos+1` é só `pos`.

```
template <typename T> void selection_sort(T* begin, T* end, unsigned pos = 0u) 
{
    if(begin != end)
    {
        for(int i = pos; i < (end - begin) + pos; i++)
        {
            if(begin[pos] > begin[i]) std::swap(begin[pos], begin[i]);
        }
        selection_sort(begin + 1, end, pos);
    }
}
```

Outra coisa, você não precisa redefinir `swap()`, pode usar `std::swap()` ao invés.

**[Código que Testei](http://ideone.com/sBJAbv)**

---

Ou você pode largar de utilizar a variável `pos` que não afeta o algoritmo:

```
template <typename T> void selection_sort(T* begin, T* end) 
{
    if(begin != end)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < (end - begin); i++)
        {
            if(begin[0] > begin[i]) std::swap(begin[0], begin[i]);
        }
        selection_sort(begin + 1, end);
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado; não posso usar o std::swap por que não posso ao mínimo incluir <algorithm>

Comment: Entendi. Nesse caso, tá ok.

Comment: Vale ressaltar no texto da resposta, que além de ter alterado a inicialização do `i`, trocando `pos+1` por `pos`, o parâmetro `pos+1` da chamada recursiva também foi alterado para `pos`. Aliás, deixar a inicialização da variável `i` como `pos+1` é melhor, visto que você já pula uma comparação desnecessária (se `i` é igual a `pos`, então comparar `begin[pos]` com `begin[i]` é redundante). Ainda, como o valor de `pos` não é alterado entre as chamadas recursivas, permanecerá sempre `0`, ele nem precisaria ser passado como parâmetro.

Comment: Realmente, o `pos` estava sem utilizada mesmo. Editei. Valeu!